# how to use db name as input control/parameter in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am  using jasper reports and want to give user to select the db name as input control and want to  use that in query.
tool used is ireport /jasper soft studio 6.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution for above question I used list of input control and then used the parameter value as

```
$P!{parametername}
```

Same as usage of table name as parameter/input control in jasper.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, following code might help you.
Ofcourse "foo DB" and "baz DB" should have same tables.

```
Connection conn;

// Change the DB depend on input value.
if (userInput.equals("foo")){
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/foo", "user", "password");
}
else if (userInput.equals("baz")){
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/baz", "user", "password");
}
else{
    // error
}

JasperReport jasper = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(your_jasper_filePath);

Map paramMap = new HashMap();
paramMap.put("param1", "some_param1");
paramMap.put("param2", "some_param2");

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, paramMap, conn);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, PdfPath);
```